# Iteration through 2 columns in dataframe for concatenate another column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, iteration, multiple-columns

```
Hours=['24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18','17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11','10', '09', '08', '07', '06', '05', '04','03', '02', '01', '00']
    result=[]
    unique_id = df['id'].unique()

    for i in unique_id:
        for j in Hours:
            filtered_data = df[(df['id'] == i) & (df['hour']==j)]
            if not filtered_data.empty:
                concatenated_names = ', '.join(filtered_data['transaction_type'])
                result.append(concatenated_names)
```

The data has three columns I'd hour and transaction_type that tells on what time what kind of transaction happened.
I want transaction column to concatenate for same time
ie if transaction A happened at 12 hr and B also at 12 hr for same I'd then result should be (A, B)
Can I write this code in more effective way?

Comment: Can you have hours other than those from the list? I doubt so, but providing a clear example would clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
result = df.groupby(['id', 'hour'])['transaction_type'].agg(', '.join)
```

Or as list:

```
result = df.groupby(['id', 'hour'])['transaction_type'].agg(', '.join).tolist()
```

If the order is important, you can first sort your data:

```
result = (df.sort_values(by='hour', ascending=False)
            .groupby(['id', 'hour'], sort=False)['transaction_type']
            .agg(', '.join)
            .tolist() # optional
         )
```

Comment: hmmm, then seems dupe.

Comment: Then why answer in the first place?

Comment: because think there is filtration.

Comment: So now you edited your `groupby` like mine? ;) I just don't understand your logic. If it's a dupe don't answer and close, else answer and leave open.